# Add object to an array does not work, when I iterate through the array I see no objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

What I want:

On the iPhone user enters few values and tap on save button.
App should store the values in an instance of `VehicleClass` and add it to an `NSMutableArray`.

Hope you can help.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VehicleClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *producerTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *modelTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pYearTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *priceTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *carArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;


- (IBAction)addCar:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showCars:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize producerTextField, modelTextField, pYearTextField, priceTextField, carArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    carArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (IBAction)addCar:(id)sender
{
    VehicleClass *newVehic = [[VehicleClass alloc]initWithProducer:producerTextField.text 
                                                          andModel:modelTextField.text
                                                          andPYear:producerTextField.text
                                                          andPrice:priceTextField.text];

    [carArray addObject:newVehic];
    if (carArray != nil) {
        statusLabel.text = @"Car saved to array.";
    }
    else {
        statusLabel.text = @"Error, check your code.";
    }
}
```

VehicleClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VehicleClass : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *producer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *model;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *pYear;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *price;


-(id)initWithProducer:(NSString *)varProducer 
             andModel:(NSString *)varModel 
             andPYear:(NSString *)varPYear 
             andPrice:(NSString *)varPrice; 

@end
```

VehicleClass.m

```
#import "VehicleClass.h"

@implementation VehicleClass

@synthesize model, price,pYear,producer;


-(id)initWithProducer:(NSString *)varProducer 
             andModel:(NSString *)varModel 
             andPYear:(NSString *)varPYear 
             andPrice:(NSString *)varPrice
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        producer = varProducer;
        model = varModel;
        pYear = varPYear;
        price = varPYear;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Maybe the problem has something to do with my init method?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Is the vehicles not stored in the `carArray`? Try `carArray = [[NSMutableArray array] init];` instead.

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray array] init]` is equivalent of `[NSMutableArray array]`. No need to try these things. Your `carArray` is `weak` and it should be `strong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`carArray` is a weak property, it should be strong.

Also: you should use `self.carArray` and not `carArray`. When you use `carArray`, you are using the underlying iVar and not the actual property. It will cause confusion later.

Comment: Indeed, when using synthesize, use `@synthesize producerTextField = _producerTextField`. This will then allow you to avoid confusion if you don't use `self.`

Answer (score 0):

Your properties should be, instead of `property (weak, nonatomic)`, `property (nonatomic, retain)`.

In your init method, put:

```
-(id)initWithProducer:(NSString *)varProducer 
             andModel:(NSString *)varModel 
             andPYear:(NSString *)varPYear 
             andPrice:(NSString *)varPrice
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        self.producer = varProducer;
        self.model = varModel;
        self.pYear = varPYear;
        self.price = varPYear;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, to check if your `carArray` has objects, instead of using `if (carArray != nil)`, use `if ([carArray count] > 0)`, because you already init it.

Comment: Thank you too for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Your carArray is weak property. carArray should be strong.

Comment: Yup, thats correct, Jeffery already told me but thanks anyway.